# Entity References Auto create between Nodes

Tags: nodes

I have node 1 has a reference to node 2 & node 3
how can I make node 2 & node 3 have a reference automatically (because they have the same reference with node1)?

Comment: Did you try the Rules module?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [hook_entity_insert()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/7.x)

> Act on entities when inserted.
>
> Parameters
>
> **$entity:** The entity object.
>
> **$type:** The type of entity being inserted (i.e. node, user, comment).

and inside the hook check if you have more than one node in the reference field, in this case you will edit all the nodes and add the reference to the others.

Comment: Thank you so much !! but I'm not sure how can I do that ? i'm new to The hooks & that stuff??

Comment: @MohK Well, you will need to write a little module to do this.

Comment: @MohK finally do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a solution that works for me on the following pages:
https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate/issues/2668010
it is using the module [prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate) and you can find the documentation on this module page.

An other solution is proposed by using the [business rule](https://www.drupal.org/project/business_rules/issues/2994745) module.